# What does "Some" mean in coq?

Tags: coq

What does the keyword/command "**Some**" mean in `coq`?

Furthermore, how can I look up its definition? Using `coq some` doesn't really help much given popularity of the word `some`.

Comment: strongly related: https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-Some-command-in-Coq-do

Answer (score 4):

`Some` is a type constructor of the `option` type. You can get some infos about such constructor by `Check`ing or `Print`ing them, to get their type or their full implementation.

Edit: what is the `option` type.

It is a type defined in Coq's prelude (again, use `Check` or `Print` to get info on this type). The type is used to state facts about the optional presence of a type: for any type `A`, `None : option A` means that there is no value, and `Some A: option A` means that there is a value (of type `A`).

Here is an example with the predecessor of a natural number:

```
Definition myPred (n:nat) : option nat := match n with
  | S p => Some p
  | O => None
end.
```

In this example, if you try to compute the predecessor of `O`, you'll get `None` (there is no such natural number). Otherwise, you get `Some p` such that `S p = n`.

Comment: then what is `option` type?

Comment: @JRR try printing and checking `option`

Comment: I've read the description of option but how do you know it has that semantics? What exactly allows you to conclude that?

Comment: I am confused, it doesn't actually return the predecessor, it returns `Some 2` sya for `Some 3` which doesn't seem to match your description...can you clarify?

Comment: The predecessor is not a total function on natural number, because 0 doesn't have a predecessor. So here I made the choice to use the `option` type to make the function total: for 0 I return `None`. For any `S n`, I return `Some n`. It is up to the user of `pred` to check which case is return an deal with `pred 0` itself.

Comment: I don't understand why did you just define the function without the `Some p` and just return `p` for `S p` and `None` for `0` (or whatever Nil value Coq has). Why invoke `Some p` (which is mysterious) and not just the actual predecessor?

Comment: Because in this case, you're function is ill-typed: `None` is a term of type `option A` (for some `A`, in our case, `A` is `nat`) whereas `p` is of type `nat`. To "lift" a `nat` into `option nat`, you need to use the `Some` constructor. Doing so, both branches of the match have the same type, which is `option nat`. You should read about the `option` type (sometimes called `Maybe`) and about total functions / typing in functional languages.

Comment: w.r.t. your comment on the first spot: `Some` is not a special command, it is a type constructor for the inductive type `option`. We should continue this discussion in a properly asked question :D don't hesitate to ping me if you create one.